# How to import the src from the tests module in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have an application that I'd like to test using `unittest` but I have some problems.
My directory structure is as follows:

```
root_dir
├── src
│   ├── cmds
│   │   ├── baz.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── bar.py
│   └── foo.py
└── tests
    ├── cmds.py
    └── __init__.py
```

I want to test the `baz` and `bar` modules from `cmds` and I'm trying to do

`root_dir> python2.7 -m unittest tests.cmds`

But in `tests.cmds` I cannot import the `cmds` package in my `src` dir.

How can I make this work?

Basically I want to test the application from `root_dir` with the `src` and `tests` directories separately.

I tried appending `src` to `sys.path`, but when I import `cmds.baz` from `tests/cmds.py` I still get an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cmds'` from unittest.

Edit:
My import and `sys.path` statement is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../src')
from cmds.baz import about
```

And the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 128, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cmds'
```

Comment: src is not a package but tests is. Why is that? Did you set the python path correctly?

Comment: Show your exact import and the full traceback.

Comment: @lbp Because I must import it when doing `python2.7 -m unittest tests.cmds`.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem that your test file is called `cmds.py` and the module directory is called `cmds` - the `module` that has no attribute is probably `cmds.py` - try `import src.cmds.baz` and see if this still gives an error?

Comment: Solved! I ran the test command from the tests directory (not from root  ) and renamed tests/cmds.py to something else and I'm still using the import statement posted above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very wrong thing to do is appending a relative path to `sys.path`. 
If you want to be sure about the path, make it as follows:

```
# assuming that the code is in test's __init__.py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                                               '../src/') ))
# now you can be sure that the project_root_dir/src comes first in sys.path
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it almost right. But as you run your tests form the root directory, your path (`'../src'`) is wrong I guess. Maybe you can do something like this:

```
import os
import sys

ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..')
sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT, 'src'))

from cmds.baz import about
```