# Python: How to Call Module from Other Path With __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python

As described in this answer [how to import module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13707428/7468395) one can import a module located in another path this way:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('PathToModule')
import models.user
```

My question is:

How can I execute this other module (and also pass parameters to it), if this other module is setup this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_something()
```

and `do_something()` uses `argparse.ArgumentParser` to work with the parameters supplied?

**I ADDED THE FOLLOWING AFTER THE FIRST QUESTIONS/COMMENTS CAME UP**

I am able to pass the parameters via

```
sys.argv[1:] = [
    "--param1", "123",
    "--param2", "456",
    "--param3", "111"
]
```

so this topic is already covered.

Why do I want to call another module with parameters?

I would like to be able to do a kind of a small regression test for another project. I would like to get this other project via a `git clone` and have different versions locally available, that I can debug, too, if needed.

But I do not want to be involved too much in that other project (so that forking does not make sense).

**AND SO MY REMAINING QUESTION IS**

How can I tweak the contents of `__name__` when calling the other module?

Comment: Presumably you can write around the `argparse` bit. What exactly is it doing?

Comment: A nicely-designed module (which is intended to be used this way) will argparse things into a set of arguments to pass to that `do_something` function, in which case you just call `module.do_something` with the right arguments.

Comment: If the module wasn't intended to be used this way, it may be that the right answer is to launch it as a `subprocess` instead.

Comment: If it is meant to work this way, but just wasn't designed very carefully, you can usually either fake out argparse in some way (if worst comes to worse hackily setting `sys.argv` or monkeypatching the module) or copy/paste the same work the top-level script code does (but simplified to only handle your case). Ugly, but the fix is to improve the other module.

Comment: so my question is: how can I tweak the contents of `__name__` when it gets supplied to the module I would like to call

Comment: That's really a whole new question, but the short answer is that you can't. (Well, you _can_, by installing an import hook, or by modifying the source code of the other module before importing it, or by doing [even more horrible things that only a lunatic would explain how to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271750/is-it-possible-to-hack-pythons-print-function/49272080#49272080)… but that's not the right answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem.

1. If the module you want to import is well-written, it should have separate functions for parsing the command line arguments and for actually doing work. It should look something like this:

   ```
   def main(arg1, arg2):
       pass  # do something

   def parse_args():
       parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
       ... # lots of code
       return vars(parser.parse_args())

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       args = parse_args()
       main(**args)
   ```

   In this case, you would simply import the module and then call its `main` function with the correct arguments:

   ```
   import yourModule
   yourModule.main('foo', 'bar')
   ```

   This is the optimal solution.
2. If the module doesn't define such a `main` function, you can manually set `sys.argv` and use [`runpy.run_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module) to execute the module:

   ```
   import runpy
   import sys

   sys.argv[1:] = ['foo', 'bar']
   runpy.run_module('yourModule', run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
   ```

   Note that this only *executes* the module; it doesn't *import* it. (I.e. the module won't be added to `sys.modules` and you don't get a module object that you can interact with.)