# python import not working

Tags: python, import

I have three files in total in python 2.7:

1. A module file in some directory (e.g. `module1.py`)
2. A different module in the same directory, which imports this module (e.g. `worker.py`)
3. A main script in the top-level directory importing `worker.py`

When the file `worker.py` looks as the following

```
import module1 as mod
```

everything works as expected (i.e. I can use `worker.mod.XXX` in my main code). But when I replace the content of `worker.py` as follows (which I expected to do the same):

```
mod = __import__('module1')
```

I get an error: `ImportError: No module named module1`. I need the latter way to handle things to automate importing modules from a list.

What am I missing here?

To be more precise: I am just looking for a way to replace the statement
    import module1 as mod
by an expression in which `module1` is a string. I have e.g. `modulname='module1'`, and want to import the module with the name of the module given in the string `modulname`. How to do that?

Comment: I believe there should be another factor, because `__import__()` is directly invoked by the `import` statement.

Comment: What factor do you mean?

Comment: Well, for example does this error appears ONLY when you change this particular line of code (and absolutely everything else, including how the program is launched is the same)?

Comment: Yes. I only try to import the same module in a different way, everything else is the same.

Answer (score 3):

`__import__(name, globals={}, locals={}, fromlist=[], level=-1) -> module`

Import a module. Because this function is meant for use by the Python
interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
`importlib.import_module()` to programmatically import a module.

The `globals` argument is only used to determine the context;
they are not modified.  The locals argument is unused.  The fromlist
should be a list of names to emulate `from name import ...`, or an
empty list to emulate `import name`.
When importing a module from a package, note that `__import__('A.B', ...)`
returns package A when fromlist is empty, but its submodule B when
fromlist is not empty.  Level is used to determine whether to perform 
absolute or relative imports.  -1 is the original strategy of attempting
both absolute and relative imports, 0 is absolute, a positive number
is the number of parent directories to search relative to the current module.

Comment: I tried to use `importlib`, but `importlib.import_module('module1')` gives the same error.

Comment: OK, how to place module which you want to import against place where you do import?

Comment: First, I do not understand your comment. Secondly, I am just looking for a way to replace `import module1 as mod` by an expression in which `module1` is used as string. I have e.g. `modulname='module1'`, and now I want to import the module with the name as defined in the string `modulname`. How to do that?

Comment: At first try to understand how MRO working in Python. This is a really ordinary theme which discussed here many times. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287054/how-to-import-the-src-from-the-tests-module-in-python

Comment: This is not helpful. This does not answer my question

Comment: @Alex: I don't think you'll get much more help here if you continue making comments like that :)

Comment: Man, this is helpful, if you do not understand the basics nobody can't help you.

Comment: I really do not understand your comments. Denis explanation is not helpful. What does it mean that `globals` is not modified? What does it mean that `locals` is unused? I do not understand. And the link provided by Denis does not seem to be related to my problem at all.

Comment: This document neither mentions `__module__` not `globals` nor `locals`. It seem to be an interesting historical document in the development of python imports, but unrelated to my problem. Also no person so far has mentioned the basic problem with my approach.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
mod = __import__('module1', globals=globals())
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This solves my problems with a concrete example.